# Modifying an HTML's "tree" of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a simple structure like so:

```
<div id="A"> 
    <div id="B"> 
        <div id="C"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="X"> </div>
```

Would it be possible, in some way (javascript, css, jQuery), to change C's position and make it X's child, for example? What are the terms to describe this situation?

Comment: You want the position changed just visually or copy the div#C to div#X?

Comment: I want the position to be visually changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. If you don't want to depend on any libraries you could do it like this:

```
document.getElementById('X').appendChild(document.getElementById('C'));
```

**The trick here is that an HTML element can exist in at most one place in the tree, but the DOM handles this for us**. Since you're telling it to make C a child of X, but C is already a child of B, the DOM knows to make C stop being a child of B. This all gets handled as a single action, so the page only has to reflow once, and that's good for performance.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible, in some way (javascript, css, jQuery)

Yes it is possible. You can use any of the following `javascript, css, jQuery`

You can try this - example using `jquery`

```
$(function () {
   $("#X").append($("#C").clone());
   $("#C").remove();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/kc0qL3nf/)
the example is using [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) of `jquery` methods

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

```
var el = $("#c").clone();
$("#x").append(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = document.getElementById('C'),
    x = document.getElementById('X');

x.appendChild(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate DOM easily. You can do it in jQuery very easily

$("#X").appendTo("#C");

You can find more at

> http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it would be possible:

```
$("#X").append($("#C"));
```

or

```
$("#C").appendTo($("#X"));
```

jQuery provides a variety of methods for DOM manipulation. You should [check them out](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#rearrange', function () {
  $("#X").append($("#C"));
});
```

```css
div { padding: 10px; }
#A { background-color: red; }
#B { background-color: blue; }
#C { background-color: green; }
#X { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Move C' id='rearrange' />
<div id="A"> A
    <div id="B"> B 
        <div id="C"> C </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="X"> X</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, try this:

```js
var c = document.querySelector('#C');
var x = document.querySelector('#X');
c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
x.appendChild(c);
```

```html
<div id="A">
  aa
  <div id="B">
    bb
    <div id="C">cc</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="X">xx</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but I am not sure how this is called.

You may try this script.

```
var c = document.querySelector("#C");
document.querySelector("#X").appendChild(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
 $('#C').appendTo('#X');
```

here's: [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tsurendra/awmhjdq9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can position it using CSS to make it visually inside the outer div#X. [More on position](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

```css
div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    #A {
        background: #abcdef;
    }
    #B {
        background: #666;
    }
    #C {
        background: green;position: absolute; top: 110px; left: 10px;
    }
    #X{
        background: orange; padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="A">
        <div id="B">
            <div id="C">Inner div</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="X">Outer div</div>
```